# How do I change the Cassandra topology + snitch in a multi AZ cluster?

Tags: migration, cassandra

I have a 9 nodes Cassandra v3.11 cluster in one availability zone with SimpleSnitchStrategy.
I want to change the snitch strategy to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and the topology to be multi AZ like this:
3 nodes in AZ-A,
3 nodes in AZ-B,
3 nodes in AZ-C.

**How should I do the migration?**
Move the nodes first and change the snitch strategy or
change the snitch strategy and then move the nodes?

As a bonus question, should I use 
`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.replace_address_first_boot=ip_address"`

or just remove the nodes and add them again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Overview

If it were me, I would first update the existing nodes to GPFS. This makes it so much easier to work with the cluster because GPFS is flexible.

Then I would add the new nodes in the new AZs to the cluster. Let's assume all 9 existing nodes are in zone A. Add 3 nodes in zone B, then 3 nodes in zone C so you temporarily end up with 15 nodes.

Finally, decommission any of the 6 nodes from zone A so you are back to 9 nodes as planned. The reason I would decommission as the last step is to make sure there is enough capacity in the cluster to minimise the risk of service interruptions.

### Seeds

As a general rule, we recommend at least two seed nodes from each DC preferably the nodes are from different racks/AZs. In your case where you only have one DC, pick one node from each AZ to use as a seed node.

Once all new nodes are added to the cluster and old nodes are decommissioned, update the `cassandra.yaml` on all nodes so they all have the same seeds but note that it is NOT necessary to restart immediately since the nodes periodically reload the seeds from the yaml.

### Switching to GPFS

Changing the snitch from `SimpleSnitch` to `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` is the easy part. The high-level steps are:

1. Update `cassandra-rackdc.properties` on all nodes.
2. Update `endpoint_snitch` in `cassandra.yaml` on all nodes.
3. Perform a rolling restart, one node at a time.

For details, see [Switching snitches in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsSwitchSnitch.html).

### Decommissioning nodes

For details, see [Removing a Cassandra node](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsRemoveNode.html). Cheers!